# call ctypes.execve with dynamic list of argumenst

Tags: python, ctypes, execve

I want to use ctypes.execve within python to call an external script. I figured already out how to call the script and how to pass a list of arguments.
But as you can see the list or arguments is quite static and I couldn't figure out how I can do this dynamically.

The list of arguments shall be a python list
eg: `argv_list = ["./tmp/arg_test.sh", "arg_1", "arg_2"]`
This python list needs to be converted somehow to match `char * const argv[]` so I can pass it to execve. <-- This is where I am struggling.

```
cmd = "./tmp/arg_test.sh"
cmd_byte = cmd.encode('utf-8')     # create byte objects from the strings

### works ### ### works ### ### works ### ### works ###

argv_0 = "argv_0"
argv_0_byte = argv_0.encode('utf-8')

argv_1 = "argv_1"
argv_1_byte = argv_1.encode('utf-8')

argv_2 = "argv_2"
argv_2_byte = argv_2.encode('utf-8')

argv_3 = "argv_3"
argv_3_byte = argv_3.encode('utf-8')

b_argv = (ctypes.c_char_p * 5)(argv_0_byte, argv_1_byte, argv_2_byte, argv_3_byte)

### works ### ### works ### ### works ### ### works ###


# int execve(const char * filename, char * const argv[], char * const envp[]);
libc.execve(ctypes.c_char_p(cmd_byte), b_argv, 0)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know about the `subprocess` module?  It has Python functions that do what you want.  No need for `ctypes`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to generate the arguments dynamically.  This is written for Windows `msvcrt` but should work for `libc` as well:

**test.cpp**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        printf("argv[%d] = \"%s\"\n", i, argv[i]);
    printf("TEST1=%s\n", getenv("TEST1"));
    printf("TEST2=%s\n", getenv("TEST2"));
    return 0;
}
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct

dll = ct.CDLL('msvcrt')
dll._execve.argtypes = ct.c_char_p, ct.POINTER(ct.c_char_p), ct.POINTER(ct.c_char_p)
dll._execve.restype = ct.c_ssize_t

cmd = b'test.exe'
args = [b'arg1', b'arg2', b'arg3']
env = [b'TEST1=hello', b'TEST2=goodbye']

# Convert Python lists to c_char_p arrays.
# Arrays should be null-terminated so adds None to the end.
cargs = (ct.c_char_p * (len(args) + 2))(cmd, *args, None)
cenv = (ct.c_char_p * (len(env) + 1))(*env, None)

dll._execve(cmd, cargs, cenv)
```

**Output:**

```
argv[0] = "test.exe"
argv[1] = "arg1"
argv[2] = "arg2"
argv[3] = "arg3"
TEST1=hello
TEST2=goodbye
```

Comment: Works! Thanks! (Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.6.7)